# Error loading init file: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil

Tags: macos, debugging, emacs

When editing a Java file in emacs on OSX (10.12.6), it often tries to format lines (say when I type a closing brace), and in the process converts spaces to tabs.  Googling revealed that to turn this off, I should add the following to my .emacs:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

However, when I add the above line to my .emacs and reload emacs, emacs reports the following error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading 
‘/Users/betirado/.emacs’:

Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
```

What is the correct solution for emacs on OSX, or what am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: There is a reasonable likelihood that the error is elsewhere in the file and occurred while editing...at least that is what often happens to me.

Comment: What @benrudgers said. Bisect your init file to find the culprit. To convince yourself, start by commenting out everything except that line you added. The line, as shown here, is correct code. So this isn't really a question about how to tell Emacs not to use tabs on OSX. It's an init-file debugging question.

Comment: In addition, if you want to inhibit using tabs *only* for Java mode, then that code is not the way to go. But that would be a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Does adding

```
(customize-set-variable 'indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

to your config make any difference?

Comment: `indent-tabs-mode` is a Boolean buffer-local variable, meaning it is perfectly acceptable to set its value to `nil`, whether locally/globally and with any setter function under the sun. OP's error is likely arising because of a mistake in their init file or some other package they are loading.